# Automatically add a reference to a foreign key inserted at the same time as the parent record

Tags: django

I'm making a database of customers in Django. Each customer can have multiple addresses, and the Customer record points to one of these addresses as being the billing address. That's set up as a foreign key, and each address has a foreign key pointing to the Customer who owns it.

The problems appears when we try to create a new customer. The new customer obviously doesn't have any addresses yet and so the dropdown for billing address needs to be empty and not required (or, better, absent). It certainly shouldn't show or allow me to choose the addresses of other customers.

Addresses are entered inline on the Customer admin page.

1. How can I enforce at least one address being created with a new customer (or ending up with at least one address after an edit)?
2. I want to require a billing address to be specified, so how can I automatically set the billing address to the first address associated with a given customer? I'll also need complaints to be raised if address pointed to as being the billing address is deleted.
3. How can I only show the current customer's addresses in the dropdown for billing address? I know of the `limit_choices_to` option but don't know how to reference the current object, given that as far as I can tell I need to use `limit_choices_to` when declaring the billing_address column in the Customer class, where `self` isn't defined and so I can't get the current object's primary key.

Here is a simplified version of the code I have so far:

```
from django.db import models

class Address(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer")
    street = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.street, self.city)

class Customer(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey("Address", null=True, blank=True, related_name="+")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that listens on the [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) for your Customer model which would check that one address was entered and if only one was entered, set that to be the billing address; if no address was entered, raise an exception.

To show only the related billing address, use the [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), which will automatically filter the entries for you.

Comment: I'm still not clear on how to set up the ModelChoiceField to show only the current Customer's addresses. What do I set the `queryset` to? `Address.objects.all()` is obviously no good since that'd be everybody's addresses, and there's no `self` defined in that context so I don't know how to filter the addresses to only this customer's.

Comment: Additionally, after some playing around I can't figure out the first part either. How do I get the number of addresses which were entered from the Customer model? In clean(), pre_save and post_save `self.address_set.all().count()` is always zero, until after it has been saved. (It's not even populated in the post_save handler.)